# prettyref- defining my references in a shorter way

Tags: cross-referencing

Currently I am working with `prettyref` which is pretty useful and works fine. The only disadvantage so far is: if I use several references in a summary the references itself become pretty long and are disturbing the reading flow (e.g. "see section 4.1.2 "Test-Chapter" on page XYZ").

Is there a possible solution to shorten the cross-reference in my way (e.g. only see section 4.1.2)? I did not find any similar questions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prettyref}

\begin{document}
\section{Example 1}
\label{sec:Example_1}
Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.
\section{Example 2}
This is my second chapter. See also \prettyref{sec:Example_1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input?

Comment: Saying `\ref{section::foo}` should provide a rather short reference.

Comment: The default `\ref` would only produce "4.1.2" the other words must be produced by some markup you have not shown.

Comment: Works fine. Prettyref seems to give more information, so now I can choose between the default \ref and \prettyref.

Comment: @Jens: So you used `prettyref` package? Please always provide a MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that other TeX.SX users can help you instead of making thousands of educated guesses...

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. Somehow I confused "hyperref" and "prettyref". Changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different options for handling cross-references. If shortness is significant, nothing is likely to been the standard `\ref` as others mentioned. However, you can also use packages which handle things differently. [`fancyref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyref) and [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) are the obvious candidates but note that `fancyref` seems to have a bug which messes up spacing with the default `vario` format. You can work around this pretty easily but since you want references to be shorter and less obtrusive, the `plain` format is a better choice anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Example 1}
\label{sec:Example_1}
\kant[1-5]

\section{Example 2}
This is my second chapter. See also \prettyref{sec:Example_1} (\verb|prettyref|).

Or see also \fref[plain]{sec:Example_1} (\verb|fancyref: plain|).

Or see also \ref{sec:Example_1} (\verb|default|).

Or see also \cref{sec:Example_1} (\verb|cleveref|).

\end{document}
```

[image: Various referencing methods]

Do see the documentation for the packages (linked above) to see the various options available. `fancyref` is highly customisable and I think the same is probably true of `cleveref`.